# DependencyProperty Binding with ValidationRule not updating Source when ValidationResult is false

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, validationrules

A ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty is bound TowWay to a DependencyProperty in 
The Control.

In the ControlTemplate :

```
  <ComboBox IsEditable="True">
     <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
          <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" 
                   Path="SomeDP" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
              <Binding.ValidationRules>
                 <vld:DeleteAfterInitValidationRule  ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
              </Binding.ValidationRules>
          </Binding>
     </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
  </ComboBox>
```

When the ValidationRule returns false

```
   return ValidationResult(false,msg);
```

The Dependency Property bound to selected item is not updated.

Is there a way to force the binding to update the source ?

*Please if any one is going to raise a discussion here about

**BindingExpression.UpdateSource()** , please supply a working example, and not just blurt it out because it sounds like the solution ,
i do not intend to use Explicit mode on my Binding.

Further more i can easily code my way around this but a good .net programmer should thrive to write less code and use the built in mechanisms supplied by the .net framework ,

**And that is the soul purpose of this question , is there a built in way of updating the source while 
notifying of a DataError ?**

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of validation not to let update the source with erroneous data?

Comment: Maybe , I was wondering if this is the correct behavior and if there is a was configure this behavior.